# using ImageFolder with albumentations in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, albumentations

I have a situation where I need to use ImageFolder with the albumentations lib to make the augmentations in pytorch - custom dataloader is not an option.

To this end, I am stumped and I am not able to get ImageFolder to work with albumenations. I have tried something along these lines:

```
class Transforms:
    def __init__(self, transforms: A.Compose):
        self.transforms = transforms

    def __call__(self, img, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.transforms(image=np.array(img))['image']
```

and then:

```
    trainset = datasets.ImageFolder(traindir,transform=Transforms(transforms=A.Resize(32 , 32)))
```

where `traindir` is some dir with images. I however get thrown a weird error:

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [16, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1024, 32, 32, 3] to have 3 channels, but got 32 channels instead
```

and I cant seem to find a reproducible example to make a simple aug pipleline work with imagefolder.

*UPDATE*
On the recommendation of @Shai, I have done this now:

```
class Transforms:
    def __init__(self):
        self.transforms = A.Compose([A.Resize(224,224),ToTensorV2()])

    def __call__(self, img, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.transforms(image=np.array(img))['image']
```

```
trainset = datasets.ImageFolder(traindir,transform=Transforms())
```

but I get thrown:

```
    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.ByteTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same
```

Comment: it seems like you are missing the finale `ToTensor()` transform that permutes the dimensions from `h`x`w`x`c` to `c`x`h`x`w`

Comment: hmm I am not sure how I can pass the `toTensor()` to this :( if I pass a list I get an error saying list is not callable. :(

Comment: oyu should "compose" the `ToTensor()` after the resize transformation.

Comment: @Shai: I have done as you suggested, but it seems to thrown another error :( I have posted it as an update to the quetsion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`ToTensorV2`](https://albumentations.ai/docs/api_reference/pytorch/transforms/#albumentations.pytorch.transforms.ToTensorV2) transformation as the final one:

```py
trainset = datasets.ImageFolder(traindir,transform=Transforms(transforms=A.Compose([A.Resize(32 , 32), ToTensorV2()]))
```

Comment: I get with this ^ approach the same error as I posted on the update `RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.ByteTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same`

Comment: @AJW we got the dimensions right, now we need the data type. How about `A.Normalize(mean=(0.485, 0.456, 0.406), std=(0.229, 0.224, 0.225)),` before `ToTensorV2`?

Comment: I have one follow up quetsion: so, when albumnetatons is loaded via ImageFolder, is it using PIL or openCV to load the image? I ask because openCV uses BGR and PIL uses RGB... and I was wondering if I need to do anything re this. but since it is ImageFolder, I assume it is PIL? i.e I just want to be sure that albumentations is not using openCV under the hood somehow (I dont think so, but worth checking with you I thought!)

Comment: @AJW AFAIK, using `ImageFolder` invokes the default `image_loader` (that you can change). Only after the image was loaded, it is passed to the `transformations`. So, if you haven't changed the default loader - you are using `PIL.Image` and RGB images.

Comment: thank you EVER so much for all your explanations.

Answer (score 1):

By looking into ImageFolder implementation on PyTorch[[link](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/_modules/torchvision/datasets/folder.html#ImageFolder)] and some proposed work in Kaggle [[link](https://www.kaggle.com/code/fanbyprinciple/learning-pytorch-10-albumentations-dataloader/notebook)]. I propose the following solution (which is successfully tested from my side):

```
import numpy as np
from typing import Any, Callable, Optional, Tuple
from torchvision.datasets.folder import DatasetFolder, default_loader, IMG_EXTENSIONS
class CustomImageFolder(DatasetFolder):
def __init__(
    self,
    root: str,
    transform: Optional[Callable] = None,
    target_transform: Optional[Callable] = None,
    loader: Callable[[str], Any] = default_loader,
    is_valid_file: Optional[Callable[[str], bool]] = None,
):
    super().__init__(
        root,
        loader,
        IMG_EXTENSIONS if is_valid_file is None else None,
        transform=transform,
        target_transform=target_transform,
        is_valid_file=is_valid_file,
    )
    self.imgs = self.samples

def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> Tuple[Any, Any]:
    """
    Args:
        index (int): Index

    Returns:
        tuple: (sample, target) where target is class_index of the target class.
    """
    path, target = self.samples[index]
    sample = self.loader(path)
    if self.transform is not None:
        try:
            sample = self.transform(sample)
        except Exception:
            sample = self.transform(image=np.array(sample))["image"]
    if self.target_transform is not None:
        target = self.target_transform(target)

    return sample, target

def __len__(self) -> int:
    return len(self.samples)
```

Now you can run the code as follows:

```
trainset = CustomImageFolder(traindir,transform=Transforms(transforms=A.Resize(32 , 32)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Albumentations library utilizes opencv that represents images as numpy array, therefore you have to provide a callable loader function that returns img as numpy array, which can be passed to albumentation transformation.

```
train_transform=A.Compose([A.HorizontalFlip(),
                           A.ShiftScaleRotate(rotate_limit=5,value=0,
                                              border_mode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT),

                           A.OneOf(
                                   [A.CLAHE(),
                                    A.RandomBrightnessContrast(),
                                    A.HueSaturationValue()],p=1),
                           A.GaussNoise(),
                           A.RandomResizedCrop(height=480,width=480),
                           A.Normalize(),
                           ToTensorV2()])


 def open_img(img_path):
     img=Image.open(img_path)
     return np.array(img)

 class Transform():
     def __init__(self,transform):
        self.transform=transform
     def __call__(self,image):
        return self.transform(image=image)["image"]



train_ds=ImageFolder(train_dir,transform=Transform(train_transform),loader=open_img)
```